# Coin Animation Issue - Works on First Collision but Fails on Second Collision

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a 2D platformer game in Unity, and I've implemented a coin animation with a coin box. When my player character collides with the coin box, the coin animation plays correctly the first time. However, on the second collision and every subsequent collision, the coin animation does not work. It only starts working again on the third collision and continues this pattern.

I've tried checking my script for any obvious errors, but I can't seem to pinpoint the issue. I'm using Unity's animation system, and the animation is set to play on trigger. Has anyone encountered a similar problem or can offer insights into what might be causing this issue? I'd greatly appreciate any guidance or solutions to resolve this bug.

Here is my all coin box script;

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CoinBox : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private SpriteRenderer _enabledSprite;
    [SerializeField] private SpriteRenderer _disableSprite;
    [SerializeField] private int _totalCoins = 3;

    private int _remainingCoins;
    private Animator _animator;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _animator = GetComponent<Animator>();

        _remainingCoins = _totalCoins;        
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (WasHitByPlayer(collision) && CheckRemainingCoins() && WasHitFromBottomSide(collision))
        {
            // Code for collision with player
            GameManager.Instance.AddCoin();
            _remainingCoins--;
            _animator.SetTrigger("FlipCoin");

            if (_remainingCoins <= 0)
            {
                _enabledSprite.enabled = false;
                _disableSprite.enabled = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private bool CheckRemainingCoins()
    {
        return _remainingCoins > 0;
    }

    private static bool WasHitByPlayer(Collision2D collision)
    {         
        return collision.collider.GetComponent<PlayerMovementController>(); ;
    }

    private static bool WasHitFromBottomSide(Collision2D collision)
    {
        return collision.contacts[0].normal.y > 0.5;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try resetting your Trigger on OnCollisionExit2D? Like:
private void OnCollisionExit2D
{
  _animator.ResetTrigger("FlipCoin");
}

Let me know if it helps!

Comment: Sorry, thanks for the solution but it did not help, Do you have another solution?